# In VBA get rid of the case sensitivity when comparing words?

Tags: vba, excel, case-sensitive

I am working on an VBA program which would allow the user to type an address and find the location by matching elements of the address with a database.

Unfortunately, I am having a recurrent problem with the case sensitivity.

For example, when I am using this code :

```
For i = 11 To lRowB
Range("B" & i).Activate
myResult = IsNumeric(Application.Match(ActiveCell.Value, manilaListRange, 0))
```

It is gonna compare the value of the active cell to a list of words from my database. Problem is, if in my active cell the word is "miami" or "MIAMI" and only "Miami" is in the database, it won't work...

Other example:

```
If Range("J6").Value = "tawi" Then
Range("J6").Value = "Tawi-Tawi"
End If
```

Same problem, only the word written with the same case is gonna work.

How can I get rid of this? It's particularly annoying and I can't rewrite my database in every case combination possible!

Comment: application.match is _not_ case-sensitive so I think you have a different issue

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There is a statement you can issue at the module level:

```
Option Compare Text
```

This makes all "text comparisons" case insensitive. This means the following code will show the message "this is true":

```
Option Compare Text

Sub testCase()
  If "UPPERcase" = "upperCASE" Then
    MsgBox "this is true: option Compare Text has been set!"
  End If
End Sub
```

See for example http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/vba-case-sensitive.htm . I'm not sure it will completely solve the problem for all instances (such as the `Application.Match` function) but it will take care of all the `if a=b` statements. As for `Application.Match` - you may want to convert the arguments to either upper case or lower case using the `LCase` function.

Comment: As a warning, this did not work for me when trying to see if two strings were identical.  I get the sense from this article that this works better for less than or greater than comparisons of text: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t3khw5f.aspx.  I am working with Salesforce IDs which are case sensitive, and even with the Option Compare Text set, VBA still found i3vz equal to i3vZ.

Comment: @rryanp  `Option Compare Text` is _supposed_ to be case **insensitive** - so what you saw is what you would expect. If you want it to be **sensitive** (so that `"i3vz" <> "i3vZ"` you can use `Option Compare Binary` instead.

Comment: Ah, I now see I was reading his post backwards.  Excellent--I'll go try Option Compare Binary--thanks a lot for the info!

Comment: For reference - Application.Match is case-insensitive to begin with, so option compare text being on or off doesn't matter.

Answer (score 23):

You can convert both the values to lower case and compare.

Here is an example:

```
If LCase(Range("J6").Value) = LCase("Tawi") Then
   Range("J6").Value = "Tawi-Tawi"
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

If the list to compare against is large, (ie the manilaListRange range in the example above), it is a smart move to use the match function. It avoids the use of a loop which could slow down the procedure. If you can ensure that the manilaListRange is all upper or lower case then this seems to be the best option to me. It is quick to apply 'UCase' or 'LCase' as you do your match.

If you did not have control over the ManilaListRange then you might have to resort to looping through this range in which case there are many ways to compare 'search', 'Instr', 'replace' etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit of hack but will do the task.

```
Function equalsIgnoreCase(str1 As String, str2 As String) As Boolean
    equalsIgnoreCase = LCase(str1) = LCase(str2)
End Function
```

Comment: It's NOT a hack at all. But all you did was repeat Vasanth's answer FIVE+ years later.

Comment: @ExcelHero thanks for the comment, you are right the idea is the same, but my answer adds more value because the function, ones declared can be used in as an Excel formula.