# Preventing duplicates in a column regardless of the case of the entry

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, case-insensitive

I type three entries in specific cells 
[A2,B2,C2] and run code to take this data to the first empty row in a table.

The code also prevents duplicates based on the entered value in cell B2. If it already exists in the range (B2:B5000) it prevent duplicates.

The problem is it does not ignore the case.

For example:
I enter value "Acetic Acid"
After awhile I add "acetic Acid" or change any letter case.

The code adds it normally without preventing.

How do I ignore the letter case?

```
Sub tarheel()
LastRow = Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
LR = Range("b10000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
For r = 5 To LR
    If Cells(r, 2) = Range("b2") Then MsgBox "This Item Name already exist, No shift will done": Exit Sub
Next
Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = Range("A2").Value
Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = Range("B2").Value
Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = Range("C2").Value
Range("A2:C2").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: This topic looks like it may solve your problem:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035660/vba-excel-get-rid-of-the-case-sensitivity-when-comparing-words][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035660/vba-excel-get-rid-of-the-case-sensitivity-when-comparing-words

Comment: Indeed interesting link, if you don't have both case sensitive and insensitive this is interesting. If you have, you can just use `LCase()` as described in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change case in VBA, you have `LCase` and `UCase`, which will respectively change all of your string into **lower** case or **upper** case.

Here is your code with the change and got ride of the useless (and ressource-greedy) select at the end :

```
Sub tarheel()

    LastRow = Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    LR = Range("b10000").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    IsIn = False

    For r = 5 To LR
        If LCase(Cells(r, 2)) = LCase(Range("b2")) Then _
            MsgBox "This Item Name already exist, No shift will done": Exit Sub
    Next

    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = Range("A2").Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = Range("B2").Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = Range("C2").Value

    Range("A2:C2").ClearContents
    'Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

thanks for all your replies and i will try it too and give feedback to you.

i could figure it out by adding this line at the top of my module.

```
Option Compare Text
```

and it fixed my problem.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your loop that compares for existing values with a case insensitive one by forcing both values to either upper or lower case.

```
For r = 5 To LR
    If lcase(Cells(r, 2)) = lcase(Range("b2")) Then
        MsgBox "This Item Name already exist, No shift will done"
        Exit Sub
    end if
Next
```

It may be more efficient to use a case-insensitive worksheet function to check the whole range at once.

```
If cbool(application.countif(Range("B5:B" & LR), Cells(r, 2))) Then
    MsgBox "This Item Name already exist, No shift will done"
    Exit Sub
end if
```

Another possible:

```
If not iserror(application.match(Cells(r, 2), Range("B5:B" & LR), 0)) Then
    MsgBox "This Item Name already exist, No shift will done"
    Exit Sub
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub tarheel()

    LastRow = Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    LR = Range("b10000").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    IsIn = False

    For r = 5 To LR
        If LCase(Cells(r, 2)) = LCase(Range("b2")) Then _
            MsgBox "This Item Name already exist, No shift will done": Exit Sub
    Next

    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = Range("A2").Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = Range("B2").Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = Range("C2").Value

    Range("A2:C2").ClearContents
    'Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```