# Highlighting searched words on Vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add a count to the word highlighted and searched so far i added icount as a string and it only counts up to 1 sometimes 2, I think my formula might be wrong and also my roommate is good with c and thinks i should change icount as a string to long or integer.

```
Sub highlightext()

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

 Dim oRange As Range
 Set oRange = ws.Cells


  Dim wordToFind As String
  wordToFind = InputBox(Prompt:="What word would you like to highlight?")

 Dim cellRange As Range
 Set cellRange = oRange.Find(What:=wordToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows,  SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not cellRange Is Nothing Then

Dim Foundat As String
Foundat = cellRange.Address
Set outws = Worksheets("product")
outws.Range("A2").Value = wordToFind


Do

    Dim textStart As Integer
    textStart = 1

    Do

        textStart = InStr(textStart, LCase(cellRange.Value), LCase(wordToFind))
        If textStart <> 0 Then
            cellRange.Characters(textStart, Len(wordToFind)).Font.Color = RGB(250, 0, 0)
            textStart = textStart + 1



        End If


    Loop Until textStart = 0


    Set cellRange = oRange.FindNext(After:=cellRange)

Loop Until cellRange Is Nothing Or cellRange.Address = Foundat

End If





 Dim icount() As String

 icount = Split(Foundat, ", ")

 outws.Range("B2").Value = UBound(icount) + 1



 End Sub
```

Comment: You need to debug this by running through the code line by line [press f8 repeatedly]. I can't tell what you're trying to do with the cellRange2 section of the code, but I doubt it's doing what you want. It seems the loops are not in the right order, or something. But - it's too much to ask us to do debugging you haven't done yourself.

Comment: In your last `For each cell in oRange` loop, change `oRange` to `Range(Foundat)` and you will be golden (or at least my test was golden .. or red rather :)). You want to loop through the range of addresses that actually found your match, not the entire range of column A again. Otherwise, you will literally highlight the first 5 characters of each cell where the `wordToFind` is not found because `Instr` will be 0.

Comment: Do you want the code to color only the **first** instance of `wordToFind` in a cell ??

Comment: Worked sort of, it highlights the first word in the sentence if  "wordtofind" is available in the cell but doesn't highlight the word itself, doesn't read through the sentence @ScottHoltzman

Comment: I want all the instances in the cell @Gary'sStudent

Comment: That is interesting @Dayday. I did a test with a word at the beginning / middle / end of the text and it highlighted them all just as you require - only the **actual** word being highlighted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fully tested code below and screenshot to go with it.

```
Sub highlightext()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim oRange As Range
Set oRange = ws.Range("A:A")

Dim wordToFind As String
wordToFind = InputBox(Prompt:="What word would you like to highlight?")

Dim cellRange As Range
Set cellRange = oRange.Find(What:=wordToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not cellRange Is Nothing Then

    Dim Foundat As String
    Foundat = cellRange.Address

    Do

        Dim textStart As Integer
        textStart = 1

        Do

            'to compare lower case only use this
            'textStart = InStr(textStart, LCase(cellRange.Value), LCase(wordToFind))
            textStart = InStr(textStart, cellRange.Value, wordToFind)
            If textStart <> 0 Then
                cellRange.Characters(textStart, Len(wordToFind)).Font.Color = RGB(250, 0, 0)
                textStart = textStart + 1
            End If


        Loop Until textStart = 0

        Set cellRange = oRange.FindNext(After:=cellRange)

    Loop Until cellRange Is Nothing Or cellRange.Address = Foundat

End If

End Sub
```

[image]

There are some pitfalls that could come up with certain words within words (like `Scott` in `Scott`ish, in my example, or `Scott` in `Scott`'s`). Perhaps these will apply to your or not, so you may need to make some adjustments.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm going to tweak it a bit to add a counter, apparent the help

Comment: I was having a problem with lowercase and uppercase so i changed your textstart

Comment: @Dayday - see [Option Compare Text](http://chandoo.org/wp/2011/12/01/case-in-sensitive-string-compare-vba/) for dealing with case senstitivity. Here is another [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035660/vba-excel-get-rid-of-the-case-sensitivity-when-comparing-words) that may be helpful.

Comment: I tried adding a count on a different worksheet to basically count the number of times the highlighed word shows up. I dim icount as integer and i feel like my loop is right but, the count only goes up to two

Comment: @Dayday - if you still need help, please post a new question.

Comment: Can't, apparently i asked a bad question

Comment: @Dayday - you can't post a new question? I don't understand. If the question you asked appeared lacking from the community, edit to make it more clear or post a new one that is more defined.