# Excel VBA – From Current Cell find the Most Previous Specific Text in a Column

Tags: excel, vba, search

My situation is, I have 5 columns, A -> E.  Column A is populated with serial numbers but also with a lot of ‘Fluff’ and column B is populated with the respective date. There is also duplicate serial numbers but only one that is populated with a respective date, the serial numbers that are duplicates have blank column B’s and that is how I know if it is a duplicate or not. Column C & D is filled with ‘Fluff’ and So is most of E.  The important thing about column E is that it contains what fruit each serial number and date is related to. The Difficult part of this is that the type of fruit is a few rows previous to the first serial number but also in column E. This distance is not fixed and the amount of serial numbers under each fruit Is not fixed. Kind of looks like this

```
Apples

12012                    
12012                    01 May 17                            fluff

Fluff                                                                       fluff
Fluff 
 12345                   02 May 17                            fluff
```

*text doesn’t actually say fluff, just gibberish.

My Goal from this to paste the information on a “Helper Page” for a plot that I will use to display the data. On the “Helper Page” Row 1 is the type of fruit, row two column A is the serial number and column B is related date. The data is to be pasted under its respective heading i.e. serial numbers under column A.

I have an attempt with the below code:

```
Sub Fruits()

    Dim Helper As Worksheet
    Dim Fruits As Worksheet

    Set Fruits = Sheets("Fruit page")
    Set Helper = Sheets("Helper Page")

    'this refreshes the helper page
     Helper.Range("A3:z11000").ClearContents

    With Worksheets("Fruit Page”)
    ' this next section of the code is responsible for finding the aircraft number that the Fruits is attached to. We know that it will be the most
    ' previous number in column E to the respective Fruit.

    ' if Apples

    For i = 2 To Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
   ‘ Search for any text that starts with GRE or RE and also see if column B is blank
         If (Fruits.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Gre*" Or Fruits.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Re*") And Fruits.Cells(i, 2).Value = "<>" Then
     ‘msgbox (“hey”)
    ' Find Fruit 
            If Range(E1, "E" & i).Find(what:="Apple", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row Then

                ' copy cells from column A and B and Paste in Apple heading on Helper Page Sheet in the next blank row
                Helper.Range("A3:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value = Fruits.Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Value

            End If

        End If
    Next
     End With

End Sub
```

I relatively new to VBA but I can’t see why this wouldn’t work. I have used  a msgbox and it appears to not be working after the 1st if Statement. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Could you supply some data with expected output? I am unclear on the logic stated above.

Comment: Sure thinng  Lets say, we have a that with the table above, before the serial number (but in same collumn but just before the original number) we add Gre or Re to indicate what apple colour it is. Then once the code is run, on another sheet (Helper) column A contains all serial numbers that matched my requirements in my If statement. Column B contains the date of the respective serial number for apples. 

We do not actually know if this therese serial numbers actually relate to apples though and thus we must check what 'heading' each serial number is under (which is in column E).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare string using a wildcard.

Change your `IF`- statement

```
 If (left(Fruits.Cells(i, 1).Value, 3) = "Gre" _ 
     Or left(Fruits.Cells(i, 1).Value, 2) = "Re") _
    And Fruits.Cells(i, 2).Value = "<>" Then
```

(not sure about what you want to check with the latest part where you compare with `<>`)

Be also carefull about Case sensitivity. If you can have "GRE..." or "gre..." in your cell, have a look for example at [In VBA get rid of the case sensitivity when comparing words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035660/in-vba-get-rid-of-the-case-sensitivity-when-comparing-words).

Comment: Thankyou!, I will give this a go today and let you know the outcome. the <> is to check if the cell is not blank.

Comment: If you want to check for an empty cell, you have to change it to `Fruits.Cells(i, 2).Value <> ""`

Comment: Thanks for that! Works as planned now until ' find fruit comment.

Comment: Write a Dot before `.Range(E1, "E" & i)`. If you write `Range`, Excel will use the `ActiveSheet`. When you want to access a member of the object of your `with`-statement, add the dot.